# WCF REST GET - "*" in the Uri causing "400 Bad request

Tags: wcf, rest, get, uri

I have a service with the following Uri template

```
Services/UserPreferences/{key}
```

The users can specify "*" in the key. This is causing a 400 bad request. I have tried encoding - replacing * with %2A. That does not help either.

Any suggestions ?

Regards,
Dhananjay

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we cannot have a "*" in the URI. Will be handling this from query parameters